# "Can’t make \"0.0\" into type number." number -1700 from "0.0" to number

Tags: macos, applescript

Why I keeping getting error "Can’t make \"0.0\" into type number." number -1700 from "0.0" to number? If I remove **as number**, the display dialog always showing.

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat
        set PID to unix id of process "JPEGmini"
        set getCpuPercent to "ps aux | grep " & PID & " | grep -v grep | awk '{print $3}'"
        set cpuPercent to (do shell script getCpuPercent) as number

        if (cpuPercent) < 5 then

            display dialog cpuPercent

        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: probably too late by the time you see this message, but don't forget the bounty you placed on this question.  It expired yesterday, and the grace period ends in 3 hours.  You have 3 decent answers to your question so there should be no problem awarding the bounty, not to mention the usual upvotes and answer acceptance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your `ps` command is returning too much information.  To illustrate what I mean, as I write, my google chrome process has a pid of 916.  Using the approach in the question, I could do `ps aux | grep 916` to see this process.  But this is not sufficient - grep will match any instance of the string "916" in the `ps` output, so if there happens to be a process with a pid of say 1916 or 9160, then this will match as well.  Also `ps aux` lists lots of other stats, many of which could also contain the string "916".  In fact if I run `ps aux | grep -c 916` there are currently 58 lines which match!

So all we need to do is tell `ps` we are only interested in a specific pid:

```
$ ps -o%cpu -p 916 | grep '[[:digit:]]'
  0.5
$
```

This will list only the cpu% for the process with the given $PID.  Piping to `grep '[[:digit:]]'` is necessary to return just the numeric percentage and strip the "CPU" column header from the `ps` output.

Wrapping this up into your original script you would have:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat
        set PID to unix id of process "JPEGmini"
        set getCpuPercent to "ps -o%cpu -p " & PID & " | grep '[[:digit:]]'"
        set cpuPercent to (do shell script getCpuPercent) as number

        if (cpuPercent) < 5 then

            display dialog cpuPercent

        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

I don't have JPEGmini installed, but this works fine for me on all other processes I have tried on my OSX 10.8.5 powerbook.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your script with the process Safari and also got the error. It seems there was more than one result being returned from the "do shell script" line... so it couldn't make the result into a number.

I changed the code to this and it worked...

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat
        set PID to unix id of process "Safari"
        set getCpuPercentCmd to "ps aux | grep " & PID & " | grep -v grep | awk '{print $3}'"
        set getCpuPercent to paragraphs of (do shell script getCpuPercentCmd)
        set cpuPercent to (item -1 of getCpuPercent) as number

        if cpuPercent < 5 then
            display dialog cpuPercent as text
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: `item -1 of getCpuPercent` is not sufficient - this will only give the last line of the `ps` output, but if there are multiple lines matched by `grep PID`, then the process we are interested in is not guaranteed to be the one listed in the last line of the `ps` output.

Comment: You're right. I should have explained it better. I was trying to show the poster of the question that the result he gets back has more than 1 value, that's why his coercion to "as number" didn't work. So I used "paragraphs of" to convert the string of multiple values into a list of the multiple values. He'll need to know something about the process to determine which result from the list he needs. Or he could use a repeat loop on the list and evaluate each result.

Answer (score 1):

I ran just the grep command and found that on my machine webkit is running a WebProcess that is tied to the Safari PID. You can see toward the end of the second line that the `-servicename` is `com.apple.WebKit.WebProcess-4881-0x1076eb0c0`. Because of that, the grep is actually finding two results and returning `"0.0\r0.0"` which it cannot make into a number.

```
$user        4881  13.3  1.2  3812416 104840   ??  R     4:27PM   0:09.57 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari -psn_0_1692061
$user        4885   0.1  0.7  3778328  56108   ??  S     4:27PM   0:00.79 /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit2.framework/WebProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/WebProcess /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit2.framework/WebKit2 -type webprocess -servicename com.apple.WebKit.WebProcess-4881-0x1076eb0c0 -localization en_US -client-identifier com.apple.Safari -ui-process-name Safari
$user        5250   0.0  0.0  2432768    520   ??  R     4:29PM   0:00.00 grep 4881
$user        5248   0.0  0.0  2433432    824   ??  S     4:29PM   0:00.00 sh -c ps aux | grep 4881
```